# Can't upload file to GCS using gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

Copying file://InstreamImpression.csv.gz [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...

AccessDeniedException: 401 Login Requiredfe13d1e0fb408639_4...:  46.75 MB/46.77 MB

CommandException: 1 files/objects could not be transferred.

Seems like whole object is being transferred but gives 401 error at the end. And it's been happening for a while.

Ran "gcloud auth login" couple times. But still the same error

I am able to upload the files from different machine.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using a service account?  It's not available via the Cloud SDK yet but you can try https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/prerelease/o/gsutil_4.4pre_retry13.tar.gz?alt=media in the meantime.

Comment: I think what's happening here is that gcloud auth login gives you a token for the gcloud client ID, but you are using a standalone version (even like the prerelease I linked earlier) that uses the gsutil client ID.  When your access token needs refreshing, this fails.

The solution is to use the gcloud-distributed gsutil only, or to uninstall gcloud and run gsutil config with the standalone gsutil version.  This is definitely painful and something the gsutil devs want to improve soon.

Answer (score 3):

It was a weird case.

The file was on windows server under "D:" drive and I was running gsutil tool from there.

i.e.
D:>gsutil -m cp xyz.csv gs:\somebucket\

I didn't have enough permission on D: drive

But as soon as I run the same command from "C:" drive it worked fine

i.e
C:>gsutil -m cp "D:\xyz.csv" gs:\somebucket\

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with how gsutil/boto handles the OS path separators on Windows, as referenced [here](https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/2884/). This should eventually get merged into the sdk tools, but until then the following should work:

Go to
google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\third_party\boto\boto\pyami\config.py

and replace the line:

```
for path in os.environ['BOTO_PATH'].split(':'):
```

with:

```
for path in os.environ['BOTO_PATH'].split(os.path.pathsep):
```

Next, go to
google-cloud-sdk\bin\bootstrapping\gsutil.py

replace the lines that use ':'

```
if boto_config:
      boto_path = ':'.join([boto_config, gsutil_path])
    elif boto_path:
      # this is ':' for windows as well, hardcoded into the boto source.
      boto_path = ':'.join([boto_path, gsutil_path])
    else:
      path_parts = ['/etc/boto.cfg',
                    os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~', '.boto')),
                    gsutil_path]
      boto_path = ':'.join(path_parts)
```

with

```
if boto_config:
      boto_path = os.path.pathsep.join([boto_config, gsutil_path])
    elif boto_path:
      # this is ':' for windows as well, hardcoded into the boto source.
      boto_path = os.path.pathsep.join([boto_path, gsutil_path])
    else:
      path_parts = ['/etc/boto.cfg',
                    os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~', '.boto')),
                    gsutil_path]
      boto_path = os.path.pathsep.join(path_parts)
```

Reload cmd and the error should go away.